# How to get all the keys present on the android keyboard using appium?

Tags: android, keyboard, appium, appium-android

While automating an android application using appium, is there a way to fetch all the keys currently displayed on a soft keyboard that get opened on clicking any input field. 
Let's suppose if we click on a numeric field, we expect that a numeric keyboard will be opened, is there a way to get all the keys displayed as a result of this click?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so? I don't think you can do that using appium. Always remember you can't automate everything.

Comment: Have you tried appium desktop ? https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/

Comment: I am trying to automate a scenario, where if we click on a field and verify specific type of keyboard open. Say numerical keyboard for numeric field.

Comment: I have tried appium desktop, but it cannot identify keywords.

Answer (score 1):

No, Appium is not exposing any API to parse keyboard visual part or get keyboard type.
You can check if [keyboard shown](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/is-keyboard-shown/), [send an event](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/actions/#actions) to it like keyUp/keyDown, [hide it](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/hide-keyboard/).

If its critical to test it, you may use new feature **[findElementByImage](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/image-elements/)**, where you will prepare images of keyboards and store it in your project, in test you will try to search for it. If element found, then your expected type of keyboard is present.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution can be type some keyword using tap on location and then get the text in search box. Now try to parse this to integer. If you are able to parse that means keyboard was numeric else alphabet. But this is not very optimized solution and needs extra care.